# Trigger is not executing to update related tables

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb

I'm trying to implement a trigger to update objects in related tables linked by foreign key. The desired result is if a record attribute IS_ACTIVE is updated to store 0, then in related objects in other 3 tables should also be updated with same value (0) in IS_ACTIVE column

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger;

CREATE DEFINER=dbadmi@% TRIGGER trigger AFTER
UPDATE ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    IF NEW.IS_ACTIVE = 0 THEN
        UPDATE table2 SET table2.IS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE table2.fkId = NEW.ID;
        UPDATE table3 SET table3.IS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE table3.fkId = NEW.ID;
        UPDATE table4 SET table4.IS_ACTIVE = 0 WHERE table4.fkId = NEW.ID; 
    END IF; 
END
```

The problem is that related objects are not updated and still storing IS_ACTIVE=1.

Comment: this works just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/CY9y7glw are you ure all tables have that id

Comment: Maybe there is an Appian platform problem because basically system is submitting an object, and these three tables are storing nested objects. So looks like there is some delay and related objects are updated again after trigger execution. I'll investigate that problem again. Thank you for response!

Comment: the trigger runs always on the server, if there is a problem, you would get an entry in the logs